# vector of objects with constructor with a vector as parameter

Tags: c++, std

My Code is the like the following:

```
struct Word
{
    Word(std::vector<char> newword);
};

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    char nice_char_array[1337];
    std::vector<char> current_word;
    std::vector<Word> wordlist;

    current_word.push_back(nice_char_array[x]);
    wordlist.push_back(*(new Word(current_word)));
}
```

It compiles, but at the point "wordlist.push_back..." the executable just hangs up.
What did I wrong?
I want to automatically generate objects without special names, just like setting values in a array or a vector. In the real code, the whole thing happens surrounded by a for-loop and some if-clauses.

Comment: Doing `*(new Word(current_word))` is basically never right.  You will leak the memory since you'll never get the pointer back.

Comment: That said we need to see how `Word(std::vector<char> newword);` is defined to able to help you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Why didn't you first try the obvious: `wordlist.push_back(Word(current_word));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c++, `new` doesn't just make a new object, it allocates a new one on the heap.

What you want to do is pass by value:

```
wordlist.push_back(Word(current_word));
```

Or even better, construct it in the vector:

```
wordlist.emplace_back(current_word);
```

Comment: Both solutions, with push_back(Word(current_word)) and emplace_back have the same problem with hanging up at a point somewhere in the stl_vector.h .
My constructor isn't even executed.

Comment: Can you give more info about "hanging"? That sounds like a bug in your constructor.

Comment: Correction: with "emplace_back" the constructor is executed.

Comment: No, if I use "push_back(Word(current_word)", my constructor isn't executed. ddd/gdb hangs up in stl_vector.h .

Comment: Your constructor should happen, and then your copy/move constructor will happen, and either hanging could cause this issue.